# How to draw one pixel

Tags: c++

My question is that, how Can I draw one single pixel on the screen using C++ native libraries and functions? I mean not to use external functions or libraries. How is it possible?

Something Like this:

```
int rgb = {255,150,113};

nativeLibrary.drawPixel(0,1, rgb);
```

A fancy example just it is.

Comment: C++ does not provide a "native" graphics library.

Comment: why anyone would want to do so any ways?

Comment: I just one to know. I'm going to do some graphics (educational, not occupational)

Comment: your question is highly platform dependent !!! which you did not specify at all.  look here for PC,Windows/DOS http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: you may find https://www.libsdl.org/ useful

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  C++ does not (yet) have any native graphics or GUI libraries.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi that depends on what you want to achieve for some purposes is GDI better for other GL,DX for other even higher layers like SDL or some engines ... all comes to target platform, fps, 2D/3D/N-D and graphics type (bitmap,vector,volumetric....)

Comment: I would add "does not have it, yet."  It's coming.  Stroustrup has wanted that for decades.

Answer (score 3):

C++ may eventually add graphics into the standard ([they were considering it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3888.pdf)), but for right now, the C++ standard does not include graphics.

You can take advantage of *other* standards in order to write a pixel to the screen, though. If you're on Linux, [there is already an answer up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527039/2620007).

If you're using VGA, you can actually [write directly to the VGA buffer](http://www.brackeen.com/vga/basics.html) (**WARNING: WAY OUTDATED** Like "meant for DOS" outdated). You would probably use C++'s inline assembly to set the render mode instead of whatever that page uses, then use a regular `unsigned char*` instead of a "far" pointer to access it. Although you probably aren't using VGA and probably don't want to use assembly (especially inline assembly).

So what do you do outside of that? Nothing, really. You need to use an external library specifically to render, so probably OpenGL or DirectX or some library making use of either.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer, there no native library to deal with images. However, if you are working in Windows API and particularly MFC, you may use CBitmap class.

Comment: CBitmap is not in Windows API (WinAPI does not have any classes). It is a MFC class.

Comment: And MFC is horribly outdated. Using it for any kind of new project is highly questionable.